# Obtener datos de una tabla usando row_factory

Tags: python, sqlite3

estoy intentando hacer una función que al usarla me introduzca los datos de una tabla, de unas rows en especifico en diferentes cajas de texto. El tema es que el `fetchall` al devolver en forma de tupla no me lo permite, sé que esta `row_factory` pero estuve buscando y no encontre forma de entender como realmente funciona, me gustaría saber de que manera actúa y no solo copíar y pegar

```
cursoor.execute("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID=?", id_lista)
lectura=cursoor.fetchall()

for data in lectura:
   idd_text.set(lectura[0])
   nom_text.set(lectura[1])
   ape_text.set(lectura[2])
   con_text.set(lectura[3])
   comentarioss.insert(1.0, lectura[4])
```

Intenté eso pero no me sirvio me tira el siguiente error: `IndexError: list index out of range` parece que es porque no puedo acceder a los datos por separado y los cuenta como uno solo, entonces busque y ví que existe el anteriormente mencionado `row_factory` pero como tambien dije, lo ví pero no vi una explicación del uso del mismo, asi que me gustaría saber como usarlo antes que ctrl+c y ctrl+v

(Agradezco la ayuda)

Comment: Tal ves [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44009452) te ayude

Comment: Me sirvió para entender el uso y la funcionalidad de cada parte del row_factory, al fina termine haciendolo como lo estaba teniendo desde un principio, me dí cuenta que el error fue estupido y en lugar de usar "data" para repetir el "for" usé "lectura"... A veces me cuesta, igualmente valoro la ayuda <3